# how to delete a file after sorting in Linux

Tags: linux, sorting

I have a huge file that needs to be sorted in Linux, for example:

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2n /dir/fileA.sam > /dir/fileA_sorted.sam
```

Because I ran out of disk space, is there a way to delete the original file (i.e. fileA.sam) after sorting it and output fileA_sorted.sam? Thanks!

Comment: If you're running out of diskspace as you write out the sorted data then no.

Comment: You can always use an alternative disk / usb key / ram disk to get round a problem of space on a temp file

Comment: I don't understand your question. If the sort succeeded and you don't need the unsorted file, then you can delete it (using `rm`). Of course you can output the sorted file (to the screen, to a printer, to whatever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a second command after running the first command by using a "&&" to separate them (or other characters, but using && implies it will only run the second command if the first succeeds)

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2n /dir/fileA.sam > /dir/fileA_sorted.sam && rm /dir/fileA.sam
```

(No warranty express or implied, try first with something innocuous before running rm)